# Need to send GCM/FCM push notification to a specific device token using azure function (.net c#)

Tags: c#, firebase, push-notification, azure-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send GCM/FCM push notification to my application, which is registered with the Firebase messaging. Currently the Firebase messaging is working with Windows. Now, due to a performance issue, I am changing it to use an Azure function.

I have created the Azure function in .NET. It does not show any error, but the code doesn't send the push notification to the specific device token which is retrieved from the SQL table. The Notification hub is configured with the FCM/GCM API key.

Complete Azure function is here; it is a azure timer trigger function:

```
string SqlConnectionString = "Server=tcp:tcpdetails.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=catalog;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=username;Password=Pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";
    GetMsg(SqlConnectionString);
}

static void sendnotification(Int32 ID, string UserName, string DeviceToken, string Title, string MsgContent, string SqlConnectionString)
{

    var connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://xxxxxxx-hub.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=cyrdSfJls6/Inpc7B19UKZiad6FaWBNDTqeapzVlZek=";
    var hubName = "hubname";
    var nhClient = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(connectionString, hubName);

    var Body = MsgContent;

    var notificationPayload = "{\"data\":{\"body\":\"" + Body + "\",\"title\":\"" + Title + "\"}}";
    var notification = new GcmNotification(notificationPayload);

    var outcomeFcmByTag = nhClient.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(notificationPayload, DeviceToken);
    Console.WriteLine("Successfully sent message: " + outcomeFcmByTag);

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update  [dbo].[fcmMsgContent] SET IsSend = 1 where ID = '" + ID + "'", conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}

private static void GetMsg(string SqlConnectionString)
{
    var mytable = new List<string>();
    var datatable_1 = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString);
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "select x1.ID,x3.UserName, x3.DeviceToken, x1.Title, x1.MsgContent from [dbo].[fcmMsgContent] x1 left join[dbo].[fcmUserMsg] x2 on x1.id = x2.MsgContentID left join[dbo].[fcmUserDevice] x3 on x3.username = x2.username where x1.IsSend = 0 and x3.UserName is not null group by x1.ID,x3.Username, x3.Devicetoken, x1.Title, x1.MsgContent";

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(datatable_1);
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    var dtparm = datatable_1.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(row => new
        {
            ID = row.Field<Int32>("ID"),
            UserName = row.Field<string>("UserName"),
            DeviceToken = row.Field<string>("DeviceToken"),
            Title = row.Field<string>("Title"),
            MsgContent = row.Field<string>("MsgContent")
        }).ToList();
    foreach (var dr in dtparm)
    {
        sendnotification(dr.ID, dr.UserName, dr.DeviceToken, dr.Title, dr.MsgContent, SqlConnectionString);
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: What version of Net are you using?  You should be using Net 4.7.2 or later and target the Net/Core you want to use.  Earlier version of Net may have issues with Encryption Modes.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for your reply. I am using .net framework and target to 4.8 but still the code not sending push notification to the device.

Comment: From your description and the fact it works with windows, I assume the issue is in the sendnotification() method and not in the code posted.

Comment: Actually this code run and there is no error but no notification message in the client side. In client application i have not done any configuration related to GCM notification hub details. currently it is using windows firebase setting, so am i missing any settings in application side? thanks

Comment: "No error" doesn't mean the code ran.  If dtparm contains no items than no notifications will occur.

Comment: dtparm contains items, i can see the records passing in VB breakpoint

Comment: I have a vb application where i have to send push notification using Azure function via notification hub. I have saved the GCM api key in the notification hub and used the Access polices full listen key in the azure function connection string. Now my azure function runs without error but no message the application end. Am i missing any settings in the application end to get the push notification message? I have not done any registration process PNS like that. Is it necessary to do any register if so how i have to do it, can you tell me in brief? thanks

Comment: I can't tell from your description where the issue is occurring.  I recommend using a sniffer and compare the working windows application with the non working Azure to see if there are any differences.